# Form php action and jquery at the same time not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, wordpress

I am trying to make custom registration in wordpress, where user enter 4 fields: Username, Email, Phone number and Password. After that they recieve validation code on their phone. I did that with Twilio api, that's jquery part and it is working, users can recieve sms, but when I put that jquery in code there is no mysql entry, when I remove it there are new entries in mysql. I hope I was clear :D
Ok, I have a button with the name "submit" and id "submitbtn"

I run this jquery at the top of the file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submitbtn").on('click',function(){
        var phone_no = $('#phone_no').val();
        var id = "<?php echo $id;?>";

              if(phone_no != '')
              {
                  var ajaxurl = "<?php echo home_url(); ?>/smsvertest/sendcode.php";
              jQuery.ajax({
                url:ajaxurl,
                type:'post',
                 data: { phone_no:phone_no,id:id
             },
              }).success(function(response){
              $("#otpjj").html(response); 
                  //alert(response);
                  console.log(response);
                 window.location.href="<?php home_url();?>/hp-compettion/register?status=true&id="+id;


              });
              }
              return false;
  });
```

Then I have this php code to insert information to mysql (wordpress):

```
<?php  
if( $_REQUEST['submit']) {
    $user_id = wp_insert_user(
        array(
            'user_login'    =>  $_POST['email'],
            'user_pass' =>  $_POST['password'],
            'first_name'    =>  $_POST['username'],
            'last_name' =>  $_POST['username'],
            'user_email'    =>  $_POST['email'],
            'display_name'  =>  $_POST['username'] . ' ' . $_POST['username'],
            'mobile_number'  =>  $_POST['phone'],
            'role'      =>  'None'
        )
    );
}
?>
```

But for some reason this part is skipped and there is no mysql entry. Maybe there is something wrong in jquery?

Comment: *Too much code*, we don't know what you are making so it's a lot to read through all of that to understand a (probably) small problem. You should provide a [mcve] and post that on here, instead a offsite resource.  *ps:* I suspect there is something wrong with it aswell if it doesn't work properly.

Comment: There is no `insert` statement in that code. It looks like you are using wordpress. You should tag that. You have too many tags as is. You need to narrow down the issue. Is the issue client side or server side? If client side is it the HTML or js/jquery?

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: Do you get an error, or anything else we can go with? Is your ajax request coming back with anything?

Comment: @Nytrix No, I updated question again... Sorry this is my first time asking here